# Call to undefined function setSurroundCount() CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to implement a pagination in my view but when I call the setSurroundCount function it gives me an error "Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Pager\Pager:ConfusedetSurroundCount() "
Does someone knows why ?

Here is my controller :

```
function index($limit=100) {

    $model = new \App\Models\TransactionModel();

    $data = [
        'title' => "Transactions",
        'transactionsHTMLTable' => $this->formatTransactionsAsHTMLTable($model->paginate($limit)),
        'pager' => $model->pager
    ];

    echo view('top', $data);
    echo view('transactions', $data);
    echo view('bottom');
}
```

Here is my view ;

```
<h3>Transactions</h3>
<?php
    echo $transactionsHTMLTable;
    // echo $pager->links();
    $pager->setSurroundCount(2);
?>

<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
    <ul class="pagination">
    <?php if ($pager->hasPrevious()) : ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?= $pager->getFirst() ?>" aria-label="First">
                <span aria-hidden="true">First</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?= $pager->getPrevious() ?>" aria-label="Previous">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php foreach ($pager->links() as $link) : ?>
        <li <?= $link['active'] ? 'class="active"' : '' ?>>
            <a href="<?= $link['uri'] ?>">
                <?= $link['title'] ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>

    <?php if ($pager->hasNext()) : ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?= $pager->getNext() ?>" aria-label="Previous">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?= $pager->getLast() ?>" aria-label="Last">
                <span aria-hidden="true">Last</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endif ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is the function formatTransactionsAsHTMLTable() :

```
function formatTransactionsAsHTMLTable($transactions) {
    $htmlTable = array();

    $table = new \CodeIgniter\View\Table();

    $template = [
        'table_open' => '<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm small">'
    ];

    $table->setTemplate($template);

    $table->setHeading('ID', 'Date', 'Subscription ID', 'Duration', 'Price', 'Proceed', 'Device', 'Country', 'Subscriber ID');

    foreach ($transactions as $key => $transaction) {
        $table->addRow($transaction['id'], $transaction['date'], $transaction['subscriptionId'], $transaction['duration'], $transaction['price'] . " " . $transaction['currency'], $transaction['proceed'] . " " . $transaction['proceedCurrency'], $transaction['device'], $transaction['country'], $transaction['subscriberId']);
    }

    return $table->generate();
}
```

I took everything from the Codeigniter 4 documentation.

If I echo $pager->links() it works. So the $pager is here but the functions setSurroundCount getFirst, getNext, ... doesn't work.
Can someone help me ?

Comment: Is - "Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Pager\Pager:ConfusedetSurroundCount() " the actual error message?

Comment: Can you please add the code of the formatTransactionsAsHTMLTable function?

Comment: @ViLar I've edited and added the formatTransactionsAsHTMLTable function

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Yes it's the actual message

Comment: @DavidGoncalves if that is the case, the error message is correct. There is no Pager method called ConfusedetSurroundCount(). I'd be checking your code.

Comment: $pager->setSurroundCount(2); This doesn't exist as @TimBrownlaw pointed out. You may want to change this code.

Comment: solution please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow [this](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html#view-configuration) sub-heading in the manual to customise the link.
Create a folder (Pagers) inside app/Views and then create a view file inside it. It will be Pagers/name_of_view_file.php.

Then you need to edit app/Pager.php to use your view file.